# How does NAND FLASH cells retain data without requirement for external power?

Tags: flash

RAM cells need constant refreshing, however NAND FLASH cells can retain data for years together. What makes this possible ?

Comment: Not all RAM cells need constant refreshing.

Answer (score 10):

What makes NAND memories non-volatile is that the logic state is retained in a physical state that doesn't depend on the supply voltage.

For EEPROM memories in general (including Flash), this is a charge trapped in a [floating gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_MOSFET).

Answer (score 3):

As clabacchio pointed out, NAND flash memories can stores information in an array of memory cells made from [Floating-gate MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-gate_transistor). Also some newer flash memory(included NAND memories) has a new technology. it's [Multi-level cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell).

I think these links will be very helpful and useful:

[How Does Flash Memory Work?](http://thingsishouldprobablyknow.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-does-flash-memory-work.html)

[HOW DOES FLASH DRIVE WORK?](http://howflashdriveworks.wordpress.com/how-does-flash-drive-work/)

[How Flash Memory Works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7JLXs5es7I)

Note: I know that they have spoken about Flash memory in these links but the technology that they have spoken about it is NAND type.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that data retention is usually guaranteed for a period, e.g. 10 years.  Also note that bit flipping can occur.  SD cards for example usually have ECC built in to correct this, to some extent.

Comment: While true this doesn't really answer the question of how they work, as opposed to the implications of using FLASH memory.